# Row number for for same value

Tags: sql-server, row

The result of my SQL Server query returns 3 columns.

```
Select Id, InItemId, Qty 
from Mytable 
order by InItemId
```

[image: result]

I need to add a column, call it row, that starts from 1 and will increase by 1, based on the initemid column with same value.

So the result should be:

[image: result2]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by initemid order by initemid) as row,
       t.*
from t;
```

Note:  There is no ordering *within* a given value of `initemid`.  SQL tables represent unordered sets and there is no obvious column to use for ordering.